# Installing Icinga2 on Server 16.04 with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: server, 16.04, repository, raspberrypi

I am trying to install `icinga2` on PI-3. I have the following set-up:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Ubuntu
- Ubuntu Server Standard 16.04
- icinga2

I execute the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:formorer/icinga
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install icinga2`
```

I get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
icinga2 : Depends: icinga2-bin (= 2.4.1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to 
be installed
Depends: icinga2-common (= 2.4.1-2ubuntu1) but >2.4.10-1~ppa1~xenial1 
is to be installed
Recommends: icinga2-doc but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
```

I am fairly new to linux/ubuntu and I am not even 100% sure what the error means or how to resolve it

Thanks for any help on this

Alexis

Comment: Hey, for broken packages run `sudo apt install -f` and then try installing dependencies separately, does the error persist?

Comment: @PauliusŠukys thanks for the response. I did as suggested.  
`sudo apt install -f`  
`sudo apt-get install icinga2-common` This installed fine but when i try to install the second dependency i get the following error  
`sudo apt-get install icinga2-bin`  
`Some packages could not be installed. The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: icinga2-bin : Depends: icinga2-common (= 2.4.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.4.10-1~ppa1~xenial1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by using `aptitude`

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`
`sudo aptitude install icinga2`

cheers
alexis

Comment: flag it as an answer to finish your question :)